# Groupby count as one column and groupby number of unique values of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as show below. which has only two columns Sector and Raised_By.

---

**My DataFrame:**

```
Sector     Raised_By        
A          Xavi
B          Ramos
C          Beckham
B          Ronaldo
A          Messi
A          Messi
C          Oven
B          Ramos
C          Ronaldo
A          Messi
C          Ronaldo
C          Beckham
```

From the above data frame I want to prepare data frame as shown below.

---

**Expected Output:**

```
Sector  Total_Number_of_Times_Raised  Number_unique_Raised_By    Unique_Raised_By
A       4                             2                         ['Xavi', 'Messi']
B       3                             2                        ['Ramos', 'Ronaldo']
C       5                             3                      ['Beckham', 'Ronaldo', 'Oven']
```

I tried following code

```
c = df.groupby(['Sector']).size().reset_index(name='Total_Number_of_Times_Raised').sort_values(['Total_Number_of_Times_Raised'], 
                    ascending =False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in version *0.25*, usage of *agg* with a dictionary (as in the other
answer), results in a warning: *FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series
for aggregation is deprecated and will be removed in a future version*.

A more modern solution is to use *named aggregation*:

```
df.groupby('Sector').Raised_By.agg(
    Total_Number_of_Times_Raised='count',
    Number_unique_Raised_By='nunique',
    Unique_Raised_By='unique').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pandas.Series.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.aggregate.html):

```
df.groupby('Sector')['Raised_By'].agg({'Total_Number_of_Times_Raised':'count','Number_unique_Raised_By':'nunique','Unique_Raised_By':'unique'}).reset_index()
```

---

Output:

```
  Sector  Total_Number_of_Times_Raised  Number_unique_Raised_By  Unique_Raised_By 
0      A                             4                        2  [Xavi, Messi]  
1      B                             3                        2  [Ramos, Ronaldo] 
2      C                             5                        3  [Beckham, Oven, Ronaldo]
```

Note: 
you could use or not `reset_index` at the end

Answer (score 2):

One option is to [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) specifying different aggfuncs

```
df.pivot_table(index=df.Sector, values='Raised_By', aggfunc=['count', 'nunique', set])
```

---

```
           count   nunique                           set
       Raised_By Raised_By                     Raised_By
Sector                                                     
A              4         2                 {Messi, Xavi}
B              3         2              {Ramos, Ronaldo}
C              5         3      {Oven, Ronaldo, Beckham}
```